# Find the domain and the range of the function $\log_{\csc x-1}(2-[\sin x]-[\sin x]^2)$,where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

Tags: functions

Find the domain and the range of the function $\log_{\csc x-1}(2-[\sin x]-[\sin x]^2)$,where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

---

For finding the domain,
$\csc(x)-1\neq 1..........(1)$
$\csc(x)-1>0...........(2)$
$2-[\sin x]-[\sin x]^2>0......(3)$
Solving the three equations and taking intersection, i found domain as $(2n\pi,2n\pi+\pi)-\left\{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6},2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2},2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}\right\},n\in I$
But i could not find the range.Is my domain correct?Please tell me the way to find the range.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain you write is correct.

Since $\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, we have
$$\begin{align}&\sin(x)\not=0,\quad \frac{1}{\sin(x)}-1\not=1,\quad\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-1\gt 0,\quad 2-[\sin(x)]-[\sin(x)]^2\gt 0\\&\iff 0\lt\sin(x)\lt\frac 12\quad\text{or}\quad \frac 12\lt \sin(x)\lt 1\\&\iff 1\lt\csc(x)\lt 2\quad\text{or}\quad \csc(x)\gt 2\\&\iff 0\lt \csc(x)-1\lt 1\quad\text{or}\quad \csc(x)-1\gt 1\\&\iff \log_2(\csc(x)-1)\lt 0\quad\text{or}\quad \log_2(\csc(x)-1)\gt 0\\&\iff \frac{\log_2(2)}{\log_2(\csc(x)-1)}\lt 0\quad\text{or}\quad\frac{\log_2(2)}{\log_2(\csc(x)-1)}\gt 0\\&\iff \log_{\csc(x)-1}(2)\lt 0\quad\text{or}\quad \log_{\csc(x)-1}(2)\gt 0\end{align}$$
Hence, the range is
$$(-\infty,0)\cup (0,+\infty).$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir.@mathlove